# Unable to add buttons to custom scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I changed the css properties of the scrollbar and the buttons disappeared. When I added this to my stylesheet:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
   display: block;
}
```

the scrollbar had two rectangles on the top and buttom but there were no arrows. When I tried clicking the top and bottom parts of each of the rectangles, it scrolled up and down. Is there a way to add only one button on each side (top and bottom) that have arrows?

CSS:

```
/* Properties of Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #4d4d4d;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: block;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #8d8d8d;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Comment: Can you shear your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `::-webkit-scrollbar-button` wrong. It's supposed to be used like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: blue;
}
```

This could also be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)